# Clickable Image regions in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have a following requirement:
- There is a static image (eg. Image of Tiger)
- What I want to accomplish is that, if I click on any particular image part, it should carry out some function.
Eg. if I click on Head portion, it should say, "You clicked on head" 
if I click on Tail portion, it should say, "You clicked on tail"

Please help me on implementing this feature using Xamarin forms (for both Android and iOS)

EDIT:
I have implemented following this reference from @LeonLu 
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/157534/clickable-image-regions-in-xamarin-forms/p1?new=1

I am able to get the tapped coordinates but they are not uniform across different resolution devices. (i.e. Tapping on head portion works on one device but does not work for other different resolution device)

My Overall Requirement:

- There is a static image of human body part (head, nose, eye, ear, shoulder, biceps, hand, ankle, chest, stomach, etc.) as shown in attached image
- I need the feature to select each body part and the selected part should be highlighted on click
- After clicking on each body part, it should perform specific action (eg. Inserting health status of each body part)
- The body part position should be uniform across all devices having different resolutions, so that that while clicking on head, it should provide correct response on all resolution devices.

[Body Parts Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APWbB.png)

Comment: The link to LeonLu's reference does not works for me, can you share how you did it ?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend `RelativeLayout` to implement this functionality.
I have created a simple demo to achieve this function.The main code is as follows:

`xaml` file

```
  <ContentPage.Content>
    <RelativeLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" >
        <Image Source="test2.jpg" 
                Aspect="Fill"
            RelativeLayout.XConstraint= "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor = 0}"
            RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height, Factor = 1}"
            RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor = 1}"
            RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height, Factor = 0}"
               >
        </Image>
        <BoxView Color="Transparent" x:Name="topView" 
            RelativeLayout.XConstraint= "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor = 0}"
            RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height, Factor = .5}"
            RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor = 1}"
            RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height, Factor = 0}" />

        <BoxView Color="Transparent" x:Name="bottonView"
            RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height, Factor=.5}"
            RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=1}"
            RelativeLayout.XConstraint= "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=0}"
            RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,  Property=Height, Factor=0.5}" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

`xaml.cs`

And use TapGestureRecognizer to achieve the touch event on the BoxView.

```
 var tapGestureRecognizer = new TapGestureRecognizer();
        tapGestureRecognizer.Tapped += (s, e) => {
            // handle the tap
            DisplayAlert("Alert", "You clicked on head", "OK");
        };
        topView.GestureRecognizers.Add(tapGestureRecognizer);

        var tapGestureRecognizer_button = new TapGestureRecognizer();
        tapGestureRecognizer_button.Tapped += (s, e) => {
            // handle the tap
            DisplayAlert("Alert", "You clicked on tail", "OK");
        };
        bottonView.GestureRecognizers.Add(tapGestureRecognizer_button);
```

The effect is like this:
[image]

Note: You can adjust the layout according to your requirement.E.g. to add the middle Tap of the Image.

Answer (score 1):

You can use absolute layout, fill the image on the layout above that place stack layout with transparent color and add click listeners on them.

Comment: Can you show some example code on how to do this ?